# Detect if piped command contains string in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with one line looking like this:

```
Command1 | Command2 | Command3
```

Command1 produces output and the other commands (Command2 and Command3) filter the output.

The filtering happens in real time line by line (using sed). I cannot wait for Command1 to finish before filtering.

I want to know if the output of Command1 contains a string (e.g. "foo bar\n\n").
I want to know this when Command1 finished. As you can see the string I'm looking for is multiple lines long.

Is this possible?

Comment: so you want `command1 | tee tempfile | command2 | command3 ; if tempfile contains your string; then something; fi`?

Comment: Note that the time between command1 finishing and command3 finishing is not likely to be very long, since they're all running in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scanning from a Process Substitution

If you create a shell function `testcmd` that checks for your string and takes an action when it's seen (note that this action can be something like running a program or creating a file; any variable that you set won't be visible to the parent shell that launched the pipeline), this would look like:

```
findit() {
  awk '
    BEGIN { rc=1 }  # starting: unless we find the pattern, exit w/ an error
    $0 ~ /foo bar$/ && rc == 1 { rc=0; next } # found the first line
    $0 == ""        && rc == 0 { exit }       # success; found our pattern
    { rc=1 }        # reset: saw a line that did not trigger a next or exit above
    END { exit(rc) }                          # honor rc as exit status
  '
}
testcmd() { findit && { echo "Found the pattern" >&2; touch found; }; }
Command1 | tee >(testcmd) | Command2 | Command3
```

This code will create the `found` file the moment `foo bar\n\n` (assuming the `\n`s are meant to represent literal newlines) is seen in the output of `Command1`, without waiting for `Command2` or `Command3` (or even waiting for `Command1` to finish, if it has more output after this string is emitted).

The `>(...)` syntax is a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), which provides a filename that can be used to write to the stdin of the compound command in `...`.

This doesn't interrupt operation of `Command2` and `Command3` because `tee` ignores an output that stops reading early and continues passing content to its other outputs as long as more input is available and at least one output is accepting writes.

---

#### Testing The Above

To test the above logic, we can define our functions as follows:

```
Command1() {
  printf '%s\n' 'first line' 'prefix foo bar' '' 'last line'
}

Command2() {
  echo "command2 reading" >&2
  in=$(cat)

  sleep 1

  echo "command2 writing" >&2
  printf '%s\n' "$in"
}

Command3() { echo "command3 read $(wc -l) lines"; }
```

...with which our combined output from `Command1 | tee >(testcmd) | Command2 | Command3` is:

```
command2 reading
Found the pattern
command2 writing
command3 read 4 lines
```

(you could potentially have `Found the pattern` before `command2 reading` -- the ordering between those is undefined; but the point is that `Found the pattern` happens before `command2 writing`, and also before command3's completion).

Comment: I've deleted my answer as yours is more thorough. The `echo >&2` might not be a good idea though, and only `touch`ing a file is prone to errors when using the script multiple times in the same place.

Comment: The intent of `echo >&2` is that it keeps content out of the pipeline. That's completely appropriate for communicating with users -- indeed, POSIX specifies stderr as the correct thing to use for "diagnostic" purposes, and that's a very broad definition.

Comment: @Fravadona, ...for example, shell prompts are written to stderr; the theoretical rationale is that information about when the program is waiting for input is diagnostic in nature; the practical rationale is that it's content meant to be seen by a human and not by another program, and that prompts should always be unbuffered (as stdin is by default, but stdout is only conditionally).

Comment: @Fravadona, ...as for the `touch`, it's an example the OP is intended to replace with whatever action they want their program to take upon detection of the condition at hand. Maybe they launch a GUI framework to pop up a message box; maybe they send a signal to another program; it's their business, not ours, to decide.

Comment: @Fravadona, (...as you may have gathered from the above, one of the things I hate and despise is software that assumes that if anything has been written to stderr, it means an error has taken place; such assumptions are completely out-of-line with POSIX guidelines -- stderr is appropriate for all informational logging, not just errors; otherwise, informational logs would go through pipes, so they'd be filtered out by the grep-esque content, would change results of things like wc, etc).

Comment: I'm totally in agreement with you; for some old scientific programs that I know of, you need to parse their `stderr` to get the parameters that you want. My point is that for an arbitrarily added test in the middle of a pipe, it might not be a good idea to write to `stderr`.

Comment: Just noticed a thinko in one of my earlier comments; should have said stderr instead of stdin, as in: *unbuffered (as stderr is by default, but stdout is only conditionally).*